# Python unrar module throws MemoryError while reading a .rar file

Tags: python, out-of-memory, unrar

I have written following code to read `.rar` files to check if they contain MDF files.

```
from unrar import rarfile

def is_contain_mdf_file(filepath) -> bool:
    try:
        if rarfile.is_rarfile(filepath):
            obj = rarfile.RarFile(filepath)
            members = obj.namelist()
            for member in members:
                content = obj.read(member)
                if content.startswith(b'MDF'):
                    return True
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error while reading archived file %s", filepath, ex)
    return False
```

While reading a rar file containing only one MDF file of size 627MB throws following error multiple times. But nevertheless the check (if the file starts with 'MDF') gets executed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 232, in 'calling callback function'
  File ".....\python\venv37\lib\site-packages\unrar\rarfile.py", line 110, in _callback
    self._data += chunk
MemoryError
```

Why I get the error and how can I prevent it? The system has enough memory to handle huge files.

OS: Windows 10
Python version 3.7

Comment: maybe you are using a 32bit python installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you get an unexpected MemoryError and you think you should have plenty of RAM available, it might be because you are using a 32-bit python installation.

The easy solution, if you have a 64-bit operating system, is to switch to a 64-bit installation of python.

The issue is that 32-bit python only has access to ~4GB of RAM. This can shrink even further if your operating system is 32-bit, because of the operating system overhead.

You can learn more about why 32-bit operating systems are limited to ~4GB of RAM here: https://superuser.com/questions/372881/is-there-a-technical-reason-why-32-bit-windows-is-limited-to-4gb-of-ram

Comment: Yes I had python 32-bit installation with OS-64 bit. Strange the MDF file when uncompressed is only around 700MB, anyways I have installed python 64-bit but now the process stuck at obj.read(member) and I have to stop application manually. Now I have changed my code, first it extracts the file into a Temp folder and then read the file - this way it works fine.